# Disable user information edition

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, user-information-list

How can I disable the user information edition?

I want that users don't be able to modify their user data.

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 Foundation.

[image: user edition window]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

> [...]Per web application, you can block the ability to Edit Personal User >Information. This security right is in Central Administration, Application >Management, User Permissions for Web Application.

Thank you [@iOnline247](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/4055/39368), ;)